# So now Ubuntu isn't free?

Tags: 20.04

I tried to update my Ubuntu software and now for updates updater asks me to go pro version. Is that mean Ubuntu isn't free any longer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong - you're making incorrect assumptions.

1. You can use Ubuntu without Pro at no cost as always.
2. You can use Ubuntu Pro for personal use at up to 5 machines for no cost as well.

But if you're a business AND want to use Ubuntu Pro, yes then there is a subscription fee. But this was always the case (previously the subscription was called Ubuntu Advantage).